# Selenium: @FindBy annotation and initElemets () method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I am new to Selenium and StackOverflow.

I apologize in advance if there is any mistake.

My question is:

How `@FindBy()` annotation works internally and why `initElemets()` method is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `initElements()` initializes all of `WebElement` and `List<WebElement>` fields with Java Reflection API. It basically changes the default `null` values to implementations of the interface using `Proxy`. It also provides sort of Lazy instantiation of the `WebElement` which means - WebElements are found (looked for?) only when needed - when you invoke operations on them.

In more depth:
`initElements` accepts `Object` or `Class<?>` as an argument and creates an object from it. Having that, `PageFactory` gets all fields in the class, verifies if any of them is a type of `WebElement` or List and initializes them.

If `WebElement` is NOT annotated with `@FindBy` then `PageFactory` tries to create selector by the variable name. Something like this `WebElement username` might actually work without annotation.

If `WebElement` is annotated with `@FindBy` then `By` object is created and connected to the `WebElement` for later use. This part is just an assumption.

Then, the instance of `WebElement` is created. Since it's an interface, it cannot be instantiated directly with Reflection API. Proxy is used to handle the creation of a `WebElement`. `PageFactory` initializes elements in provided Page Object with newly created instances of WebElements using Reflection.

Both, `WebDriver` and `WebElement` implements interface `SearchContext` which also tells the `WebDriver` how to look for the element. Is it in the whole page source or scope is reduced to the particular `WebElement`. That's why we can search elements through other elements like this: `element.findElement(By.id("username"))`.

Hope I explained it a little bit!